# Question about Thevenin theorem

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

So I am currently working on thevenin theorem and I come across this question.
[image]

So in the question there is a circuit consist of two batteries with same voltage but different internal resistance, a variable resistance R and a 10 ohm resister R0. And we have to find the value of resistance of R to adjust the voltage across R0 to specified values.

Sorry, but I am still trying to understand the theorem so I have little clues on solving this question. If I have to state one difficulty I noticed then I guess It would be finding the value of currents flowing through the internal resistance of the two batteries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't need anything other than joining the identical sources together and treating the combination as one single 24 volt source feeding via 0.8||0.9.

Comment: @Andyaka I understand your point but the question stated that thevenin theorem has to be applied in this question. So how should I apply the theorem to show my understanding of it?

Comment: Apply Thévenin at the junction point of the 0.8 and 0.9-ohm resistors. You end up with a \$V_{th}\$ and an \$R_{th}\$ resistance (as Andy aka suggested) feeding your resistance \$R\$ and loaded by \$R_0\$.You are left with a simple resistive divider suplied by \$V_{th}\$ whose output should be 4 V, 8 V etc. The only unknown in the equation is \$R_0\$ that you can easily solve.

Comment: @VerbalKint Sorry but is it possible to show the solution with a bit more details? In fact I find no question resemble mine (same voltage and different internal resistance) on all websites I visited so far and I only barely understand the solutions of questions of the same topic while not able to finding them out in the first place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't need anything other than joining the identical sources together and treating the combination as one single 24 volt source feeding via 0.8||0.9.

> *@Andyaka I understand your point but the question stated that thevenin
> theorem has to be applied in this question. So how should I apply the
> theorem to show my understanding of it?*

- Turn the left-hand 24 volt source and its respective series resistor (0.8 ohms) into a current source in parallel with its equivalent resistance.
- Do the same for the right-hand 24 volt source and its respective series resistor (0.9 ohms) into a current source in parallel with its equivalent resistance.
- Combine the current sources into one current source
- Combine the 0.9 ohm and 0.8 ohm into one resistor then...
- reverse the process and determine the combined equivalent voltage source and the combined series resistance and then solve standard voltage divider equations to ascertain the voltage across \$R_0\$ based on what value \$R\$ is.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Now I see. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I confess that I prefer to stick with the original voltage sources : ) Especially here with a \$V_{th}\$ of 24 V and a \$R_{th}\$ resistance of 423 mohms. If you do the maths ok, the value you want for a 4-V output is 49.57 ohms.

Comment: @CD-ROM [Do you know what to do next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png) if you are happy with the answer?

Comment: @CD-ROM Yes, and the other thing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png

Comment: @Andyaka First combine the two batteries into a single one with internal resistance of 0.8||0.9 (~0.4235 ohm). Then remove R for the analysis. The thevenin voltage is 24V and the thevenin resistance is 0.8||0.9 + 10 = ~10.4235 ohm. Then apply the voltage divider equation and change the subject to get the formula R = 2400/V(r0) - 10.4235. I guess that's it?

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry I forgot it. Thanks a lot and I can now understand the theorem!

Comment: @VerbalKint Yeah Now I get the correct answer. Many thanks!